# Indecomposable contracting maps on the integers

Tags: co.combinatorics, semigroups-and-monoids

$\def\ZZ{\mathbb{Z}}$Call a function $f : \ZZ \to \ZZ$ "contracting" if
$$|f(j) - f(i)| \leq |j-i|$$
for all $i$, $j \in \ZZ$. The contracting functions form a monoid under composition; call it $C$. An element of a monoid is called a "unit" if it is invertible; the units of $C$ are the functions $x \mapsto \pm x + k$. An element of a monoid is called ``irreducible" if it is not a unit and cannot be factored as the composition of two non-units.

> Question 1: What are the irreducibles of $C$?

To give two nonobvious examples, the maps $x \mapsto |x|$ and $x \mapsto \begin{cases} x & x \geq 0 \\ x+1 & x < 0 \end{cases}$ are both irreducible.

The problem which I actually want the answer to is a slight variant of $C$: Define $C_2$ to be the monoid of maps $f : \ZZ \to \ZZ$ which are contracting and obey $f(i) \equiv i \bmod 2$. So what I would really like to know is:

> Question 2: What are the irreducibles of $C_2$?

If you prefer finite monoids, I am fine with you working with $\{ 0,1,2,\ldots,n \}$ instead of $\ZZ$ for either question.

Comment: Consider a function that increases linearly up to $-n$, then zigzags up and down irregulary between $-n$ and $n$ for much more than $n$ steps, then increases linearly to $\infty$. If we consider a "random" such function in some sense, it seems believable to me that the function is irreducible with high, but not quite $1$, probability. So there might not be a classification of irreducibles, any more than there is a classification of irreducible polynomials in two or more variables - they're just all the ones that don't happen to be reducible.

Comment: @WillSawin You and Nate seem to have incompatible intuitions (compare his last paragraph to your comment).

Comment: There seem to be a bunch of papers on the finite version (without mod 2) computing Greens relations which should be related but they didn't seem to go very far.  I expect the finite case behaves differently because the cardinality of the image should be relevant to irreducibility

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg Can you tell me what to search for to find papers? I guessed "contraction monoid" and "Lipschitz monoid" but, while both of those are mathematical objects that people write papers about, neither of them was this object.

Comment: @DavidESpeyer, maybe this is no longer relevant.  The papers on the finite case all seem to start from https://dergipark.org.tr/tr/download/article-file/435131.

Comment: For the finite case, cardinalities of these monoids 1,4,17,68,259,950,3387,... seem to appear on OEIS as [A081113](http://oeis.org/A081113), which is defined as the number of paths of length $n-1$ a king can take from one side of an $n\times n$ chessboard to another side.

Comment: They have a formula for these cardinalities,$$\sum_{k=1}^nk(n-k+1)T(n-1,k-1)$$where $T(n,k)$ are the Motzkin numbers,$$T(n,k)=\sum_{0\leqslant2i\leqslant k}\binom n{k-2i}\left(\binom{n-(k-2i)}i-\binom{n-(k-2i)}{i-1}\right)$$

Comment: But are there any irreducibles in the finite case?? I could not find a single one up to $n=7$, neither in $C$ nor in $C_2$.

Comment: As for cardinalities of $C_2$ in the finite case, these seem to coincide with [A153334](http://oeis.org/A153334), "number of zig-zag paths from top to bottom of an $n\times n$ square whose color is that of the top right corner", 1, 1, 4, 8, 24, 52, 136, 296, with the formula$$\begin{cases}(n+1)2^{n-2} - 2(n-1)\binom{n-2}{\frac{n-2}2},&\text{$n$ even},\\ (n+1)2^{n-2} - (n-1)\binom{n-1}{\frac{n-1}2},&\text{$n$ odd}\end{cases}$$

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე Isn't $f(x) = x+1$ for $x < a$, $f(x) = x$ for $x \geq a$ an irreducible element of $C$ in the finite case, for any $0 < a \leq n$?

Comment: No, unless I am misinterpreting the whole thing. For example with $n=3$, $(1223)$ (i.e. $0\mapsto1$, $1\mapsto2$, $2\mapsto2$, $3\mapsto3$) is $(1232)\circ(0112)$, is not it?

Comment: I see. This probably points to something wrong in how I am defining irreducible. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: In the finite case it seems that every noninvertible element is fixed by an nonidentity idempotent on the left so you should maybe replace irreducible by maximal in the J-order.  This is proved in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1804.10057.pdf but note they with with the opposite semigroup because they act on the right

Comment: The buzzword for the finite case is contractions on a finite chain

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'll solve question 2, on $C_2$.

I will prove the irreducibles are those that only have one or two bends, verifying a prediction of [Nate](https://mathoverflow.net/a/422987/18060) (and disproving a prediction of [myself)](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/422985/indecomposable-contracting-maps-on-the-integers/422994#comment1087029_422985).

Call a "run" a maximal interval on which $f$ is linear. Clearly $f$ is linear on $[a,b]$ if and only if we either have $f(i)=i+1$ for all $i= a,\dots, b-1$, or $f(i) = i-1$ for all $i= a,\dots, b-1$. Then $[a,\dots, b]$ is maximal if, in addition, we have $f(a-1) = f(a)+1$ and $f(b+1) =f(b-1)$ in the first case or $f(a-1)=f(a)-1$ and $f(b+1)=f(b-1)$ in the second case.

I'll show that if $f$ is irreducible and $f$ has a run then $f$ has exactly one run. The number of runs is the number of bends minus one, so this is equivalent to Nate's claim.

The length $b-a$ of a run is a nonnegative integer, so if there is any run, there is a run of minimal length. If $[a,a+k]$ is a run of minimal length, then $f$ must be linear on $[a-k,a]$ and $[a+k,a+2k]$ as otherwise these intervals would contain a shorter run (the longest linear subinterval touching $[a,a+k]$).

Assume wlog the run of minimal length is increasing. Then $f( a-i ) = f(a)+i = f(a+i)$ for $0\leq i \leq k$ and $f(a+k-i) =f(a+k)-i = f(a+k+i)$ for $0 \leq i \leq k$.

So if we let $g(n)$ be given by the rule that $g(n) = n $ for $n \leq a$, $g(n) = 2a-n$ for $a\leq n \leq a+k$, and $g(n) = n-2k$ for $n\geq a+k$, and $h(n) = f(n)$ for $n \leq a$ and $h(n) = f(n+2k)$ for $n \geq a$, then $f =g \circ g$.

So if $f$ is irreducible, since $h$ is certainly not invertible (we have $k\geq 1$ since runs have length at least $1$), $g$ must be invertible, i.e. translation or reflection. So $f$ has the same number of runs as $h$, i.e., one.

Answer (score 8):

Too long for a comment, but not completely thought out:

Call a point $x$ a "bend" if $f(x-1) = f(x+1)$.  I think if we restrict to the subclass of $C_2$ with finitely many bends then the only irreducible ones are those with $1$ or $2$ bends.  Here is an idea for a proof:

If $f(x)$ has an odd number of bends then up to flipping sign it must have a global minimum $m$. If we take the right most $y$ point attaining that minimum.  The claim is that we can write $f$ as a composition $g \circ f'$ where $g(x) = |x-y| - m$ and $f'$ is in $C_2$ with one fewer bend.

If $f(x)$ has an even number $2n$ of bends with $n > 1$ then the claim is that we can write it as a composition of $h \circ k$ with $k$ having just 2 bends and $h$ having $2n-2$ bends.  The idea being that $k$ accounts for the leftmost pair of bends, and $h$ accounts for the rest, just shifted.

Comment: sorry for posting here, but I saw you deleted your helpful comment to my recent AMGM question. In case I need to thank you in a paper, you can send me email so I know your name, if you wish to do so.

Comment: @AbdelmalekAbdesselam  referring to me as "MathOverflow user Nate" or something similar is fine.

Comment: acknowledgement made in https://arxiv.org/abs/2309.07358